# Is Nogi's house original or rebuilt?

Tags: japan, architecture, history

Nogi's house and shrine ([乃木神社](http://www.nogijinja.or.jp/)) in [Roppongi](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tokyo/Roppongi#See) is a nice place but I am not sure whether it is an original building or a reproduction.

In what year was it built?

[image] [image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [it was built in 1902](http://gurutabi.gnavi.co.jp/en/spot/item/53190/) and is the original (generation 1 building).

It's only open on the [12th and 13th of September every year](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/japan/tokyo/sights/religious/general-nogis-residence) - anniversary of his death.

Comment: Might *"[building generation 1] 1902"* actually mean that the building had several generations and the first generation was built in 1902?

Comment: @nic I suppose it *might*, but then you'd think remarks on the building would include the current one as well.  It seems more likely that it's generation 1.